Python function to merge columns into one column
I am trying to build a function, to apply to different columns with a csv file. The purpose of the function is to combine multiple columns into one, using the combine_first method described here: How to merge/combine columns in pandas?
I like to create a function, with parameters: csvName, ColName, NumberOfCol, and generate a new (combined) column for that csv file. Because there are different sets of columns that need to be grouped (and there are multiple csv files), I like to use a function on each set of columns.
Example columns (showing only the ones that need to be merged, the DF has many other columns that I need to retain):
DF = {'A1': [tree, grass, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],  
    'A2': [np.nan, np.nan, bird, fly, np.nan, np.nan],
    'A3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, cat, dog]}

DF["A"] = pd.concat([DF["A1"].\
                           combine_first(DF["A2"]).\
                               combine_first(DF["A3"])], 
            axis=1)
DF.rename(columns={"A1":"A"}, inplace=True)

The resulted column will become:
DF = {'A': [tree, grass, bird, fly, cat, dog]}
I like to make this operation into a function, so I can enter the name of the csv, the column name (e.g., A), and number of columns that need to be merged
I have something like this at the moment:
   def column_merger(csvName, ColName, length:int):
        OriginalNameList = []
        for number in range(length):
            OriginalNameList.append(ColName + str(number))
    
        NewList = OriginalNameList[1:]

        for name in Newlist:
            NewList.append()
        command = []
        command.extend([.combine_first(SurveyName[NewList[name]]) for name in range(NewList)])

But it is not working. Any suggestion very much welcomed! Thank you!

I think this approach does what you're looking for, but note that I had to turn DF into a DataFrame object, since I assume that's what it's supposed to be
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


DF = pd.DataFrame({
    'A1': ['tree', 'grass', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'A2': [np.nan, np.nan, 'bird', 'fly', np.nan, np.nan],
    'A3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'cat', 'dog']
})

# use 'stack()' to combine the columns, dropping the nan values
# use 'reset_index()[0]' to get the desired data out of the stack as a Series
# and then use 'to_frame('A')' to convert that series back into a DataFrame 
# with the desired column name 'A'
DF = DF.stack().reset_index()[0].to_frame('A')
print(DF)

#        A
# 0   tree
# 1  grass
# 2   bird
# 3    fly
# 4    cat
# 5    dog

Note that you can do each of those steps separately (without chaining them) if you want to see the intermediate results
DF = DF.stack()
print(DF)
DF = DF.reset_index()[0]
print(DF)
DF = DF.to_frame('A')
print(DF)  # final result

I should point out, however, that there are pending implementation changes to the stack function which will alter its behavior in Pandas 3.0 (NB: at time of writing, Pandas is currently at v2.2). You can read more about this in the Pandas 2.1 release notes

It works very well! Thank you so much for taking the time to help!! Your solution is neater than what I had before
(Apologies that I can't vote your answer up, because I don't have enough reputations yet).

Glad I could help. If this worked for you, please click the check mark to "accept" this answer; that way others can see that this question has been answered.
